# How to return time from Date Time data type?

Tags: outsystems

I'm having trouble of how I can get the time value of a Date Time data type.

Eg.

```
1900-01-01 10:00:00.000
```

I only need to get the time `10:00:00.000`

How can I get the time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I found it. There's a built in function in OutSystems that we can used.

```
DateTimeToTime()
```